# Power BI can't connect to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, powerbi, mysql-workbench, powerbi-desktop

I have created a database in MySQL called 'Sales Data' at server 127.0.0.1. I log into this database on MySQL workbench as user root with my password, and everything works fine.

On Power BI, I am trying to connect by doing Get Data -> MySQL Database -> Server: 127.0.0.1, Database: Sales Data -> user: root and my password (the same one that is working for MySQL Workbench. I am getting an error that says it can't find my Sales Data db. I have also tried connecting through localhost as the server. Still doesn't work.

[image][image]

I installed MySQL with the oracle installer, which automatically installed all the necessary connectors, etc. Any idea why it can't find my database?

Comment: perhaps there is a distinction between "sales data" and "Sales Data" ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I thought the same, but idk how to change that. I am inputting "Sales Data" in Power BI even though the error message is all lowercase. It also hasn't asked me to enter my credentials after the first time. I wanted to try doing user: root@localhost instead

Comment: I recently learned mysql has case insensitive character sets.  Wonder if that could be involved.  Try with a database with a simple lowercase name - no spaces eg.

Comment: Hmm yeah just tried changing it to 'salesdata' and still getting the same error

Comment: I was reading https://resagratia.com/2020/10/how-to-connect-mysql-to-power-bi/ .  It looks as if you first select the database, and only later you need to identify.

Answer (score 0):

The name used "sales data" is unknown because it's the connection name , not the database name , if you tried logging in MYSQL you will find the database name under the title *SCHEMAS*.
[image: Screen capture]

Answer (score 0):

-> you need to write server ip with port like
server: 127.0.0.1:3306
database: Sales Data
-> then on next screen change selected option 127.0.0.1:3306 to 127.0.0.1:3306/Sales Data